# How can I replace string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm using emoji API and I get emoji unicode's like this `U+1F425` to be able to show emoji's in jsx. I have to replace `U+1F425` to `\u{1F425}` ; basically I just need to get `1F425` from the API.

Emoji.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Sidebar from "../../Sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./Emoji.css";

const Emoji = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {
  const [type, setType] = useState([]);
  const getEmoji = () => {
    fetch("https://emojihub.herokuapp.com/api/all/group_animal_bird")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((dat) => (console.log(dat), setType(dat)));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEmoji();
    console.log(type);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
              {type.map((emo) => (
                <>
                  <h6>{emo.name}</h6>
                  <span>{emo.unicode}</span> // This Not
                  <span>{"\u{1F985}"}</span> //This works
                </>
              ))}
    
    </>
  );
};

export default Emoji;
```

Comment: Have you tried to show emo.htmlCode?

Answer (score 1):

- you can use function to replace the format in the received data before rendering it in jsx.
- in your case, you can try to splitting the string,converting hexadecimal part to unicode point and then recontructing in the desired format.
- In midify code, convertUnicode function that takes Unicode string(U+1F425) and return in (\u{iF425} format. Then in the getEmoji function each emo object is mapped to replace in unicode propertywith Unicode character.

  ```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import Sidebar from "../../Sidebar/Sidebar";
    import "./Emoji.css";

   const Emoji = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {
     const [type, setType] = useState([]);

     const convertUnicode = (unicode) => {
       // Split the Unicode string and get the hexadecimal part
       const hexString = unicode.split("U+")[1];
       // Convert hexadecimal to decimal
       const decimalCode = parseInt(hexString, 16);
       // Convert decimal code to Unicode character
       return String.fromCodePoint(decimalCode);
     };

     const getEmoji = () => {
       fetch("https://emojihub.herokuapp.com/api/all/group_animal_bird")
         .then((resp) => resp.json())
         .then((dat) => setType(dat.map(emo => ({ ...emo, unicode: convertUnicode(emo.unicode) }))));
     };

     useEffect(() => {
       getEmoji();
     }, []);

     return (
       <>
         {type.map((emo, index) => (
           <div key={index}>
             <h6>{emo.name}</h6>
             {/* Render the converted Unicode */}
             <span>{emo.unicode}</span>
           </div>
         ))}
       </>
     );
   };

   export default Emoji;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
function convertUnicode(unicode) {
    // Extract the hexadecimal part after "U+"
    const hex = unicode.substring(2);
    // Convert hexadecimal to Unicode escape sequence format
    const unicodeEscape = `\\u{${hex}}`;
    return unicodeEscape;
}
```

// Example usage:

```
const emojiUnicode = "U+1F425";
const unicodeEscapeSequence = convertUnicode(emojiUnicode);
console.log(unicodeEscapeSequence); // Output: \u{1F425}
```

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are nothing but characters.
You have to convert that code to hex and then convert that hex code to string.

```
 const res = '1F425';
// Convert your string to hex code
 const resHex = +`0x${res}`;
// Convert Hex to string
 String.fromCodePoint(resHex); // You can render this directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one line answer

```
function convertUnicode(unicode) {
    // split by +, use 2nd element and add \u infront with {}
    return `\u{${unicode.split("+")[1]}}`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: emo.htmlCode[0] }}></span>
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -1):

Slicing the emoji code got from API should work...

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Sidebar from "../../Sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./Emoji.css";

const Emoji = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {
  const [type, setType] = useState([]);
  const getEmoji = () => {
    fetch("https://emojihub.herokuapp.com/api/all/group_animal_bird")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((dat) => (console.log(dat), setType(dat)));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEmoji();
    console.log(type);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
              {type.map((emo) => (
                <>
                  <h6>{emo.name}</h6>
                  <span>{"\u{" + emo.unicode.slice(2) + "}"}</span> //This should work now.
                </>
              ))}
    
    </>
  );
};

export default Emoji;
```

...you may try this out.